# Equivalent for Python's list comprehension

Tags: python, go

I am playing with Go but I am having a very hard time doing things that are very simple in other languages.

I'd like to reproduce a [Python comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
array = [a for a in anotherArray  if (some condition)]
```

What is an elegant way to do it in Go? I'd really like to simplify my code, especially when using a function on array. For example:

```
min = min(abs(a[i], b[j]) for i in range(n)
                          for j in range(i, n))
```

Comment: The second example doesn't work in python: abs takes 1 argument, not 2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Interestingly enough, [Rob Pike](https://github.com/robpike) just proposed (18 hours ago) the library [filter](https://github.com/robpike/filter) which does a bit what you want:

See [for instance Choose()](https://github.com/robpike/filter/blob/719f41397a0cd4c4b12b3176a49821de294efb75/apply.go#L27-L34)

```
// Choose takes a slice of type []T and a function of type func(T) bool. (If
// the input conditions are not satisfied, Choose panics.) It returns a newly
// allocated slice containing only those elements of the input slice that
// satisfy the function.
```

[Tested here](https://github.com/robpike/filter/blob/719f41397a0cd4c4b12b3176a49821de294efb75/apply_test.go#L67-L70):

```
func TestChoose(t *testing.T) {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    expect := []int{2, 4, 6, 8}
    result := Choose(a, isEven)
```

As [`twotwotwo`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2714852/twotwotwo) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848406/golang-equivalent-for-pythons-list-comprehension#comment44102741_27848524), the [GoDoc for this library](http://godoc.org/robpike.io/filter) states:

> Package `filter` contains utility functions for filtering slices through the distributed application of a filter function.
>
> The package is an experiment to see how easy it is to write such things in Go. It is easy, but **`for` loops are just as easy and more efficient**.
>
> **You should not use this package.**

This caveat is reflected in the document "[**Summary of Go Generics Discussions**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vrAy9gMpMoS3uaVphB32uVXX4pi-HnNjkMEgyAHX4N4/mobilebasic?pli=1)", section "[**Functional Code**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vrAy9gMpMoS3uaVphB32uVXX4pi-HnNjkMEgyAHX4N4/mobilebasic?pli=1#h.97ujgd64iyd)":

> These are the usual [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) such as `map`, `reduce` (`fold`), `filter`, `zip` etc.
>
> **Cases**:
> typesafe data transformations: `map`, `fold`, `zip`
>
> **Pros for using generics**:
> A concise way to express data transformations.
>
> **Cons for using generics**:
> The fastest solution needs to take into account when and in which order to apply those transformations, and how much data is generated at each step.
> It is harder to read for beginners.
>
> **Alternative solutions**:
>
> **use `for` loops and usual language constructs**.

---

Update Q1 2022: with the first integration of generics in Go (see for instance "[Tutorial: Getting started with generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics)"), you now have a possible [mapreduce implementation with generics in Go](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/rzpa5y/a_mapreduce_implementation_with_generics_in_go/).
See [tip.playground](https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/EJ4wICXH1OM), and the [`github.com/kevwan/mapreduce/v2`](https://github.com/kevwan/mapreduce/tree/v2.0.0) project.

Comment: I tend to agree with Pike's readme--use `for`. Possibly forever but certainly for now, Go is an imperative language that favors straight-line code. The language probably isn't going to change to make other approaches easier, more or less regardless of how many folks wish it would. The point of the package was (after getting complaints) that you can do that kind of thing if you feel you truly *need* it with `reflect` and stuff, not that he thinks you should.

Comment: @twotwotwo yes, I suppose '`for`', plus some '`go generate`' should be enough.

Comment: Note the prominent "You should not use this package." at http://godoc.org/robpike.io/filter

Answer (score 4):

If what you are looking is indeed python list comprehension, there is no such syntactic equivalent in go AFAIK.

The way to do it is to create a function that take a slice and a function (to test the condition) and return a new slice.

EDIT:
Well looks like there is already such a feature in Go. cf VonC

Comment: Not in Go (just a normal library on GitHub) and the documentation advises you not to use it; it's just an experiment to show you can do it if you want to.