# Golang assign value to deep nested structure

Tags: javascript, go, dynamic, struct, slice

I'm learning Go and so far really enjoying it. Coming from a JS background, there are certain patterns and best practices that I'm still discovering.

What would be the best way to get and assign a value to a deeply nested object in Go using a Object path? For example, in JS it could be done like this...

```js
var children = [{children:[{children:[{a:1}]}]}]
var child = "0.children.0.children.0".split('.').reduce((c, p) => c[p], children)
child.a = 2
console.log(children[0].children[0].children[0].a)
```

Comment: With nested structs, you'll just have to do `A.B.C ...`. With maps, arrays, or slices, the you'd just do `a[0]["x"] ...`.  There are no other idiomatic shortcuts.

Comment: Python's list comprehensions offer a different way to do functional operations like this. [This answer addressing another question involving list comprehensions in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27848524/539810) is worth reading as it explains that it's possible but not worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a general solution, you can do it using package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), but it's better to avoid it if possible (e.g. if you know the types and the "path" at compile time, simply use field [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) and [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)).

Here's a demonstration. A helper function that sets a "deep" value specified by `string` elements may look like this:

```
func set(d interface{}, value interface{}, path ...string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(d)
    for _, s := range path {
        v = index(v, s)
    }
    v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
}
```

The `index()` function used above may look like this:

```
func index(v reflect.Value, idx string) reflect.Value {
    if i, err := strconv.Atoi(idx); err == nil {
        return v.Index(i)
    }
    return v.FieldByName(idx)
}
```

This is how we can test it:

```
type Foo struct {
    Children []Foo
    A        int
}

func main() {
    x := []Foo{
        {
            Children: []Foo{
                {
                    Children: []Foo{
                        {
                            A: 1,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
    path := "0.Children.0.Children.0.A"
    set(x, 2, strings.Split(path, ".")...)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i36wueuYgG)):

```
[{Children:[{Children:[{Children:[] A:1}] A:0}] A:0}]
[{Children:[{Children:[{Children:[] A:2}] A:0}] A:0}]
```

As can be seen from the output, the "deep" field `A` denoted by the `string` path `"0.Children.0.Children.0.A"` changed from the initial `1` to `2`.

Note that fields of structs (`Foo.A` and `Foo.Children` in this case) must be exported (must start with capital letter), else other packages would not be able to access those fields, and their value could not be changed using package `reflect`.

---

Without reflection, knowing the types and "path" prior, it can be done like this (continuing the previous example):

```
f := &x[0].Children[0].Children[0]
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f)
f.A = 3
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/y0x3JJjUO0)):

```
&{Children:[] A:2}
&{Children:[] A:3}
```

The general solution of this (without reflection):

```
func getFoo(x []Foo, path ...string) (f *Foo) {
    for _, s := range path {
        if i, err := strconv.Atoi(s); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            f = &x[i]
            x = f.Children
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Using it (again, continuing the previous example):

```
path = "0.0.0"
f2 := getFoo(x, strings.Split(path, ".")...)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f2)
f2.A = 4
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", f2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QABDDX0Rz1)):

```
&{Children:[] A:3}
&{Children:[] A:4}
```

But note that if we're only dealing with `int` indices, it does not make sense anymore to declare `path` to be `...string` (which is `[]string`), an `int` slice would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Great example!

Comment: How would I do it without reflection.  For example, using a path with only integers "0.0.0" and then return the struct Foo that can be mutated?

Comment: Yes, but that requires you to know the exact length of nesting and isn't flexible. If the structure is consistent but nested length varies how can I access the nested object to update the tree?  Something comparable in JS is working with immutable data structures.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for your help!